# add_menu_page() with different name for first submenu item

Tags: plugin-development, menus, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

The [`add_menu_page` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) says to pass the menu title as the second parameter:

```
add_menu_page('Page Title', 'Menu Title', ...);
```

When adding more pages later via [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page), the main page becomes the first entry in the submenu:

[image]

---

However, I want the first item in the list to have a different name (but still point to the same page), the way Wordpress itself does it:

[image]

---

How could I accomplish that in my plugin?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can make the 'slug' for the submenu page equal that of the top level page, and they'll point to the same place:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'my_menu_output' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Submenu Page Title', 'Whatever You Want', 'manage_options', 'my-menu' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Submenu Page Title2', 'Whatever You Want2', 'manage_options', 'my-menu2' );
}
```

E.g.

[image]

Comment: This would result in duplicate entries, since Wordpress automatically creates a submenu page for the main page.

Comment: I remember skimming through the core code last week and running into a note that said something like: "Add default submenu item IF USER HASN'T ALREADY".  It checks to see if there's a submenu item pointing to the top level item.  If there is, it doesn't add the default.

Comment: I want when i create custom menu i want to display some tables and data as other tabs are display a tutorial link or some function help will be appreciated

Comment: Exactly what I waas looking for. Thanx :P

Comment: this works fine for me too still...

Comment: This works like a charm. Make sure you have at least one submenu other than the first submenu since first one is pointing to parent slug. If not your submenus will not be visible.

Comment: Obviously still works for WP 5.9. Since the callback for add_menu_page is optional, I eliminated that, and just ensured that the slug for the menu and first submenu are the same. As @MichaelLewis said, this results in eliminating the first default/redundant submenu. Bravo!

Answer (score 12):

Make the slug of the parent menu item and sub-menu same (first one item) as below

```
function actions_recent_bids_add_admin_page(){

    add_menu_page(
          'Recent Bids',
          'Auction Reports',
          'manage_options',
          'wc-auction-reports',
          'actions_recent_bids_list',
          'dashicons-chart-area',
           56
    );

    add_submenu_page(
          'wc-auction-reports',               // parent slug
          'Recent Bids',                      // page title
          'Recent Bids',                      // menu title
          'manage_options',                   // capability
          'wc-auction-reports',               // slug
          'acutions_customers_spendings_list' // callback
    );


    add_submenu_page(
          'wc-auction-reports',               // parent slug
          'Customer Spending',                // page title
          'Customer Spending',                // menu title
          'manage_options',                   // capability
          'wc-acutions-customers-spendings',  // slug
          'acutions_customers_spendings_list' // callback
    );

    add_submenu_page(
          'wc-auction-reports',          // parent slug
          'Customer Bids',               // page title
          'Customer Bids',               // menu title
          'manage_options',              // capability
          'wc-acutions-customers-bids',  // slug
          'acutions_customers_bids_list' // callback
    );
}

add_action('admin_menu','actions_recent_bids_add_admin_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just spent forever looking for this and the correct way is not listed here. You want to use

```
remove_submenu_page('parent_slug','parent_slug');
```

to the end of your function

Comment: But the question is about adding a duplicate menu, not removing one?

Comment: It could be accomplished by removing the original entry and then adding a new one with a different name with the same slug. Just an idea!

Answer (score 0):

Update!!! If you are not sure whether the parent menu exists, you can first check it as follows:

```
function contacts_page_submenu(){
    // Check if menu exist ( if Parent Exist ), we don't need it but he wrote :|  ( i'm editor)
    if(menu_page_url('contacts-parent-menu', false )){
        // Change First Submenu Text
        add_submenu_page(
            'contacts-parent-menu', // Slug Parent required
            'Contacts Settings', 
            'Contacts Settings',
            'manage_options',
            'contacts-parent-menu', //Slug Parent required
            'contacts_submenu_callback' // Give Callback Parent Name
        );
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'contacts_page_submenu');
```

Tested and works in WordPress 6.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Answer (score 0):

function content_adder_menu() {
add_menu_page(
'Content',     // Page title
'Content',     // Menu title
'manage_options',    // Capability required to access
'content-adder',     // Menu slug
'content_adder_page' // Callback function to display the page
);

```
// Add a submenu page under the top-level menu
add_submenu_page(
    'content-adder',    // Parent menu slug
    'Add Content',      // Page title
    'Add Content',      // Menu title
    'manage_options',   // Capability required to access
    'add-content',      // Menu slug
    'add_content_page'  // Callback function to display the page
);
```

}

// Callback function for the top-level menu page
function content_adder_page() {
// Display your top-level menu page content here
echo '';
echo '

## Welcome to Content

';
// Fetch posts from the 'post' post type
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post', // Adjust post type as needed
'post_status' => 'publish', // Fetch only published posts
'posts_per_page' => -1, // Fetch all posts
);

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>List of Posts</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore global post data
} else {
    echo '<p>No posts found.</p>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

}

// Callback function for the submenu page
function add_content_page() {
// Display your submenu page content here
echo '';
echo '

## Add Content

';
// Check if the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Process the form data here
$url = sanitize_text_field($_POST['url']);
$content = wp_kses_post($_POST['content']);

```
    // Save or use the submitted data as needed
    // For example, you can save it to a custom post type or display it
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'Your Post Title',
        'post_content'  => $content, // The content you want to save
        'post_status'   => 'publish', // Publish the post
        'post_author'   => 1, // Author ID (1 is typically the admin)
        'post_type'     => 'post', // Post type (change if needed)
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    if ($post_id) {
        // The post was successfully inserted
        echo 'Post ID ' . $post_id . ' created.';
    } else {
        // There was an error
        echo 'Error creating the post.';
    }

    echo "<p>URL: $url</p>";
    echo "<div>Content: $content</div>";
} else {
    // Display the form
    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<label for="url">Add URL:</label> <br>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="url" id="url" /><br />';
    echo '<label for="content">Add Content:</label> <br>';
    echo '<textarea name="content" id="content" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Content" class="button button-primary" />';
    echo '</form>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'content_adder_menu');

Answer (score -2):

Simply add this:

```
$submenu['my-menu'][0][0] = 'My New Menu Title';
```

For debugging purposes, you can do a `print_r($menu)` to check the whole WP menu.

Comment: Hackedy hack. Use the API!

Answer (score -3):

```
add_submenu_page(
        'tut_theme_settings',       // parent slug
        'Front Page Elements 2',    // page title
        'Front Page 2',             // menu title
        'manage_options',           // capability
        'tut_theme_settings2',      // slug
        'theme_front_page_settings' // callback
    );
```

if different name of first sub-menu create same slug of parent and first child and call same function

Comment: How is it different from the accepted answer? And to which action this should be hooked.